# R: Reading a File in Chunks from a Website

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Here is some R code that reads a CSV file from an internet website, saves it to the temporary directory, and then imports it into R:

```
# Set the URL of the CSV file
url <- "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_200.csv"

# Set the path for the temporary file
temp_file_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")

# Download the file from the URL and save it to the temporary file
download.file(url, destfile = temp_file_path, mode = "wb")

a <- read.csv(temp_file_path)
```

**My Problem:** For larger files, sometimes after downloading the file into the temporary directory, when I try to import the file into R -  I get an error stating that `"Can not allocate vector of size ..."` .

**My Question:** I was wondering - in such situations, is it possible to import the file into "chunks" (e.g. 10 MB chunks) in an effort to avoid this error? Can someone please show me how to do this if it is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [read_csv_chunked](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim_chunked.html)

Comment: Or prehaps duckdb and/or arrow when working with larger-than-memory datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider something like this :

```
library(data.table)
url <- "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_200.csv"
temp_file_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
download.file(url, destfile = temp_file_path, mode = "wb")
df <- fread(file = temp_file_path, skip = 50, nrows = 50)
```

With the code above, you read the rows 50 to 99